# Помогите составить SQL запрос

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы. В одной комнаты, в другой жители комнаты. В первой таблице "rooms" (комнаты) есть поле count_seat (сколько можно поместится жителей всего), и поле house (id дома). 
Во второй таблице "peoples" (жители) есть поле id_room (id комнаты). Мне нужно определить кол-во свободных мест в доме. Сделал так:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(a.count_seat) AS all_klv,COUNT(b.id) AS bron_klv FROM rooms a LEFT JOIN peoples b ON b.id_room=a.id WHERE a.house=1"); 
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res)
$klvMest = $row2['all_klv'] - $row2['bron_klv'];
```

Мне выводится очень большое число, которое в 10 раз больше правильного. 
По моим анализам, он почему-то несколько раз забирает из таблицы rooms одне и теже комнаты, ибо когда я написал запрос на вывод комнат, то выводилось много дупликатов, полагаю столько же сколько и жителей. 
Почему так? Как мне исправить эту проблему именно в таком запросе, если это возможно? Пожалуйста, объясните.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку

SELECT (select SUM(count_seat) from rooms a1 where a1.house=a.house) AS all_klv, COUNT(b.id) AS bron_klv FROM rooms a LEFT JOIN peoples b ON b.id_room=a.id WHERE a.house=1

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a1 where a1.house=a.house) AS all_klv, COUNT(b.id) AS bron_klv FROM rooms ' at line 1

Comment: Ошибки не вижу без таблиц.
Может русскую букву набил.

Comment: А так работает?

SELECT (select SUM(count_seat) from rooms where house=1) AS all_klv, COUNT(b.id) AS bron_klv FROM rooms a LEFT JOIN peoples b ON b.id_room=a.id WHERE a.house=1

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё работает по этому запросу! Отредактируйте ответ

Comment: Запрос в ответе должен работать. Буковки "a" перебил. Проверьте.